# Possible PhpStorm issue: cachegrind.out.12780.0cd9d9

Tags: phpstorm

I'm getting massive amounts of data being stored in `/var/tmp` (many gigabytes).  I see files that are named `cachegrind.out.10000.002f0b` and variations of this name.

Any ideas what could cause this and how to rectify it?  Is this related to the issue cache which is a setting on PhpStorm?  I'm finding that this appears to be causing Ubuntu to slow down.

Comment: Highly doubt -- the only place where this kind of info can *possibly* be generated as result of PhpStorm actions is running PHPUnit tests with code coverage (with you should be clicking on purpose anyway). If you do not use it -- look at your settings in php.ini -- some users when configuring xdebug for some reasons enabling performance data collection (`xdebug.profiler_*` settings) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed these two lines in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`:

```
;xdebug.profiler_enable=1
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/var/tmp"
```

This seemed to sort it.